# group list by property and where it appears more than once

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects of type student.

```
 public class Student
 {
    string FirstName
    string Surname
    int Age
 }
```

I want my to group students with the same surname together and return a list of those surnames where a surname appears more than once. Eg,

```
 Surname
 Bloggs
 Joe
 Bloggs
 Smith
 Tom
 Smith
```

My new list would just have

```
 Bloggs
 Smith
```

Here is the code I am currently using which works however is there a way in my linq statement to specify to return surnames that appear more than once?

```
var res = hldList.GroupBy(hld => hld.MyID).ToList();

foreach(var id in res)
{
    var total = id.Count();
    if(total >1)
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group list on `SurName` and filter those whose count is greater than 1 :

```
var duplicateSurNames = ldList.GroupBy(hld => hld.Surname)
                              .Where(g=>g.Count() > 1)
                              .Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Close.  It should be `var duplicateSurNames = ldList.GroupBy(hld => hld.Surname).Where(g=>g.Count() > 1).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();`.  Incorrect case on `Surname` and Count needs parenthesis after it, as it's a method/function and not a property.

Comment: @RobertMcKee you are right I forgot count parenthesis but case is not  big issue

Answer (score 2):

```
hldList
  .GroupBy(hld => hld.SurName)
  .Select(hld => new { key = hld.Key, count = hld.Count() })
  .Where(hld => hld.count > 1)
  .ToList();
```

if you don't want the counts, you can add another projection at the end:

```
  .Where(hld => hld.count > 1)
  .Select(hld => hld.key)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: No need of creating anonymous object